# make a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have some lists which are made by a for loop. when I run my code it gives the lists like this:

```
[000000000, 11111111, 4444444]
[44444444, 55555555, 66666666]
```

How can I make a list of lists then I can handle my data. my python version is 2.6.6

Comment: can you post your loop?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: @ Maroun just I want to put them in a list. then it would be like a matrix

Comment: So you expecting a common list which can hold the list created in your for loop ?

Comment: I put my codes in the main Q

Comment: @ pad: the codes are added

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
master_list = []
for something in something_else:
    # do some stuff, generate temp list
    master_list.append(temp_list)
```

After all your iterations, `master_list` will be a list of lists that were generated during your processing step.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this::

```
List_of_list = []
for i in range(0, n):
     # add list in List_of_list
     List_of_list[i].append(list)
```

after this all list will be add with `List_of_list` like `[[list1],[list2],......[list n]]` and then you can use this using loop/iteration .